# Error: failed to download "kubernetes-dashboard" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)

Tags: kubernetes

I am installing Kubernetes dashboard using helm 3 following the [docs](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/banzaicloud-stable/kubernetes-dashboard) but getting below error:

```sh
  [root@localhost ~]# helm repo add kubernetes-dashboard https://kubernetes.github.io/dashboard/
    [root@localhost ~]# helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "kubernetes-dashboard" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈ 
    [root@localhost ~]# helm install kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard kubernetes-dashboard
Error: failed to download "kubernetes-dashboard" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That chart is old and installs 1.x version of kubernetes dashboard.

From docs [here](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/k8s-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard) use below command to install latest Kubernetes dashboard version 2.x

```
helm repo add k8s-dashboard https://kubernetes.github.io/dashboard
helm repo update
helm install dashboard-release k8s-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard --version 2.2.0
```

Comment: I just do not know why using this command `[root@localhost ~]# helm install k8s-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard kubernetes-dashboard --version 2.2.0
Error: failed to download "kubernetes-dashboard" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)` failed,and this `helm install k8s-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard --generate-name --version 2.2.0` success,I could not using `kubernetes-dashboard` by name?@Arghya Sadhu

Comment: name needs to be first parameter before chart..check updated answer

Comment: I got the point,I write the name with the wrong order.@Arghya Sadhu Thank you for your patient.

Answer (score 2):

The chart mentioned by [Arghya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839482) is a must to use this period.

Alongside his answer, I want to mention very important info about the custom values of the Helm release :

```
#these are mine
rbac:
  clusterReadOnlyRole: true # <--- YOU NEED this one
  clusterAdminRole: false
extraArgs:
  - --enable-skip-login
  - --enable-insecure-login
  - --system-banner="Welcome to Company.com Kubernetes Cluster"
```

As you can see `rbac.enabled` is not enough, you need to specify also `rbac.clusterReadOnlyRole=true` or to give more access to the Dashboard, set true to `rbac.clusterAdminRole`.